# Electric Gate Project further development

Tags: sensors

[image]

Newbie here, hoping to extend my control of electric gate system.

Here is where I am at, and will then go on to explain where I want this to get to.
My gate system is an old "out of the box" BFT Libra Panel, and all's working well.

3 pairs of sensors controlling daytime entry and exit for simplicity of delivery vehicles coming into the property etc ( dont want to install keypads and the like) family members have " Blippers" to remotely operate, without waiting for sensors to trigger, so gates are open ready before approaching.

Also I have added to this a Wi-Fi trigger ( as the control board has strong wi-fi signal which I have achieved with range extenders)
this can open the gates with " Hey Google" and a ewelink button on android... all working well, now what I would like is a simple "chime" to sound in the property to notify that the gate is open. There is a feed on the Board that delivers 24 VAC when the gate is open ( really meant for a gate light ) which i was hoping to use to trigger a sound in the property, from say a plug in wi-fi chime device.

- Q1, how to best use the gate board trigger signal of 24 VAC to enable a chime device to sound?
- Q2. Link this chime to also notify ewelink and Google to join up the dots?

Comment: You could just use an IFTTT sensor to detect when the gate is open or closed and run the chime off IFTTT. You could also connect that to your google and other seervices.

Comment: I will seek out a 24vac IFTTT outdoor sensor as my board is running off that 24 volt AC system and cabling is set up as such appreciated
Anyone know of a device please add a link

Comment: You can sense the 24VAC signal or you can electrically isolate the IFTTT circuit from that by just magnetically sensing the position of the gate. The IFTTT circuit and the gate would just run from the same mains wiring, but have nothing else electrically in common then. Let us know what you did and how it worked via comments.